# How to select a column and replace last digits of the result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to mask the last 2 digits of a column so I can generate a report for a client, but dont want him to get the phone numbers of my data base.

Found some results here but none of them does what I want.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I don't think 2 digits is enough

Comment: Think is it, remember that snapchat leak ? they used 2 and nobody could ever use those numbers to SPAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer and change it to do what I want, here's what I did to mask the phone number.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT( LEFT( phone, LENGTH( phone ) -2 ) ,  'xx' ) 
FROM TABLE
```

The -2 is to indicate that I want the last 2 numbers replaced and the XX is what its going to show instead of the 2 numbers, this way the numbers are masked.

I'm just sharing what I'm learning, sorry if theres an aswer for this already in another way.

Answer (score 0):

select REPLACE(column,SUBSTRING(column,-2),'xx') From table;

Comment: I'm new to mysql so my question is, whats the difference between concat and replace in this use ? is it faster ?